# Select gets nothing from the table when checking if a row already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i'm trying to create a row in my table but i'm also verifying if there is a record I need to reference in another table. That is inside of a stored procedure and has been working for other tables until I get to this one that is more complex and has more parameters. I created a stored procedure for testing and it seems that there is something wrong with my parameters, because when the number of parameters increase, all of my selects return 0 even though I have the record in the table I was looking.

Here is my code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CriarPF`(
nome TEXT,
 cpf varchar(11),
 sexo text,
 escolaridade text,
 data_nasc DATE,
 fornecedor BIT(1),
 estado_civil text,
 email TEXT,
 identidade text,
 cidade TEXT,
 estado TEXT)
BEGIN

if (select not exists (select * from sexo where nome = sexo)) then
 call CriarSexo(sexo);
end if;

if ((select exists (select * from escolaridade where nome = escolaridade))=0) then call CriarEscolaridade(escolaridade);
end if;

if ((select exists (select * from estado_civil where nome = estado_civil))=0) then call CriarEstadoCivil(estado_civil);
end if;

if ((select exists (select * from cidade where nome = cidade))=0) then call CriarCidade(cidade, estado);
end if;

call CriarPessoa(pessoa);
insert into pessoa_fisica (Pessoa_idPessoa, cpf, Sexo_idSexo, Escolaridade_idEscolaridade, data_nasc, fornecedor, Estado_civil_idEstado_civil, email, identidade, Cidade_idCidade)
values (last_insert_id(), '01433333333', (select idSexo from sexo where nome = sexo), (select idEscolaridade from escolaridade where nome = escolaridade), '2012-12-12', 0, (select idEstado_civil from estado_civil where nome = estado_civil), 'bug@bug.com', '1234567', (select idCidade from cidade where nome = cidade)); 

END
```

Comment: If you have sample data to include with the question, you can include it with the question as that will be helpful for review and debugging.

Answer (score 1):

When a variable and a column has the same name then the variable has a priority. If you need to access the column value you MUST specify a table. I.e. in

```
if (select not exists (select * from sexo where nome = sexo)) then
```

both `nome` and `sexo` are input variables from the procedure parameters, whereas in

```
if (select not exists (select * from sexo where sexo.nome = sexo)) then
```

`sexo.nome` is table column and `sexo` is a variable.

Take this into account and correct all the code.

PS. In shown code statement the external SELECT is excess, `if not exists (select * from sexo where nome = sexo) then` is enough.

Comment: I also tried to change tha variable's name to Sexo or nomeSexo but the problem persisted. Maybe I should alway specify the column as `sexo.{variable}`. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Akina is correct that MySQL allows variable names to look like column names -- and that affects queries.  To fix this, give your parameters names that are unlikely to interfere with column names.

I use a convention such as this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CriarPF`(
nome TEXT,
     in_cpf varchar(11),
     in_sexo text,
     in_escolaridade text,
     in_data_nasc DATE,
     in_fornecedor BIT(1),
     in_estado_civil text,
     in_email TEXT,
     in_identidade text,
     in_cidade TEXT,
     in_estado TEXT
)
```

`in_` indicates that this is an read-only parameter ("input").